# Can one who lived be the subject of 'leave'?

Tags: vocabulary

> “I’ve come to bring Harry to his aunt and uncle. They’re the only
> family ***he has left*** now.”
>
> -- *Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone* by J.K. Rowling.

OALD says *leave somebody* is *to have family remaining after your death* ([OALD, leave #10](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/leave)). But the case’s subject is not Harry’s parents but Harry. Can Harry, who lived, be the subject of ‘leave’?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not the meaning of *left* in this sentence, though I can understand your confusion. Left here is not a form of *leave*; rather it is equivalent to *remaining* (*all that is left*).  That would be [definition #7](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/leave) from your link:

> **leave** 7. *be left* [transitive]  to remain to be used, sold, etc
>
> *Is there any coffee left?*
>
> *How many tickets do you have left?*

So in this case, they're discussing Harry's family. Some people might have a lot of living family members, but Harry does not. He used to have parents, but he doesn't any longer. So if you take the family he was born with and subtract the family members who died, you're left with *the family he has left* or *the family (members) that are remaning*: the Dursleys.